# An old (19-20th century) usage of "but"

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

Here's the sentence 
"Not a wrong in this world but had him as its champion ; not a cause of liberty or reform but gained his support."

The statement falls in a paragraph of introduction of a character(in a biography).

Now I understand the use in "What is it but the lack of knowledge of the English grammar" - meaning it's nothing other than "the lack of...".

But I'm seeing something like the above literally for the first time.

Thanks

Comment: Note that there is a negative in the construction before the _but_ (_Not a wrong in this world but ..._). This marks it as a [***Nobbut**-Cleft*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf) construction. The sense of _but_ involved means 'other than, except for', which is pretty ancient. On the other hand, cleft sentences of various kinds are pretty ancient, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [definitions](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/but) of "but" is "except".  Your sample sentence, with some implied words added back in, is something like

> [There was] not a wrong in the world *except* [such a wrong as] had him as its champion...